# Gradle print vs println

Tags: gradle, groovy, stdout, stderr, println

I understand the difference between `print` and `println` methods.
But why Gradle with default logging level prints output with `println` but doesn't with `print` or `printf`?

*TaskProgress.groovy*

```
public class TaskProgress {

    private static final String PROGRESS_SYMBOLS = '_/\\_';
    private static final int MAX_POINTS = PROGRESS_SYMBOLS.length() - 2

    AtomicBoolean inProgress = new AtomicBoolean(true)
    int currentChar = 0
    int delta = 1

    private TaskProgress() {}

    static TaskProgress doProgress() {
        Log.error("START PROGRESS")
        def taskProgress = new TaskProgress();
        taskProgress.startProgress()
        return taskProgress
    }

    private void startProgress() {
        Thread.start {
            Log.error('STARTING:')
            while (inProgress.get()) {
                if (currentChar > MAX_POINTS) {
                    delta = -1
                } else if (currentChar == 0) {
                    delta = 1
                }
                println PROGRESS_SYMBOLS[currentChar] // it works
                print PROGRESS_SYMBOLS[currentChar] // it doesn't work
                currentChar += delta
                if (!inProgress.get()) break;
            }
            Log.error('STOPPING:')
        }
    }

    public void stopProgress() {
        Log.error("STOP PROGRESS")
        inProgress.set(false)
    }

}
```

*buid.gradle*

```
task progress {
    doLast {
        def progress = TaskProgress.doProgress()
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        progress.stopProgress()
    }
}
```

When I use `print` in the main thread it works okay. Is it a defect?
I raised a topic on official gradle forum: [**Gradle print vs println**](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-print-vs-println/21334)

Comment: printf probably flushes the output stream.  You can check by adding `System.out.flush()` to the line after your `print`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it. And it works. But printed the result after `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` and  `Total time: 7.467 secs` rows. But still it is strange.

Comment: Probably it would be better to ask on https://discuss.gradle.org/ about it.

Comment: @Opal, I have already attached a link to the question.